# Mount a volume in docker using nodejs on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, volumes, dockerode

I try to mount a volume in docker container using nodejs app on windows.
When I try this command on the cmd:

> docker run -it -v C:\Users\User\data:/stuff:rw ubuntu bash

it works and the container contains the volume.
But if I try to do this using nodejs (dockerode module), it does not work.
My code:

```
var dockerode = require('dockerode');
var docker = new dockerode();
var stream = require('stream');

docker.createContainer({
    Image: 'ubuntu',
    Cmd: ['ls', 'stuff'],
    'Volumes': {
      '/stuff': {}
    },
    'Binds': ['C:\Users\User\data:/stuff:rw']
  }, function(err, container) {
    container.attach({
      stream: true,
      stdout: true,
      stderr: true,
      tty: true,
      'Binds': ['C:\Users\User\data:/stuff:rw']
    }, function(err, stream) {
      stream.pipe(process.stdout);

      container.start({
        'Binds': ['C:\Users\User\data:/stuff:rw']
      }, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  });
```

The problem is that it prints nothing (the stuff directory is empty).
When I use the same code on mac, it works fine.
How can I fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did u happen to get a solution for this??

Comment: Not yet.. I moved to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your path delimeters - without correct escapes, binds are resolved as `C:UsersUserdata:/stuff:rw` (`\U` maps to just `U`, etc.).

So instead of

```
'Binds': ['C:\Users\User\data:/stuff:rw']
```

Use:

```
'Binds': ['C:\\Users\\User\\data:/stuff:rw']
```